# OpenFST on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS error installing

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, openfst

Want to install OpenFST 1.6.2. Ran ./configure, make, make check. I get this output. Please advice. Thanks.

```
fst_test.o: In function `fst::internal::CompactFstImpl<fst::ArcTpl<fst::TropicalWeightTpl<float> >, fst::(anonymous namespace)::CustomCompactor<fst::ArcTpl<fst::TropicalWeightTpl<float> > >, unsigned short, fst::DefaultCompactStore<std::pair<int, fst::TropicalWeightTpl<float> >, unsigned short>, fst::DefaultCacheStore<fst::ArcTpl<fst::TropicalWeightTpl<float> > > >::Init(fst::Fst<fst::ArcTpl<fst::TropicalWeightTpl<float> > > const&, std::shared_ptr<fst::DefaultCompactStore<std::pair<int, fst::TropicalWeightTpl<float> >, unsigned short> >)':
fst_test.cc:(.text+0x3c35f): undefined reference to `fst::Int64ToStr(long, std::string*)

make[3]: Entering directory '/home/kkoenen/stt/kaldi-master/tools/openfst-1.6.2/src/test'
/bin/bash ../../libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=link g++  -std=c++11   -o fst_test fst_test.o ../lib/libfst.la -lm -ldl 
libtool: link: g++ -std=c++11 -o .libs/fst_test fst_test.o  ../lib/.libs/libfst.so -lm -ldl -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/home/kkoenen/stt/kaldi-master/tools/openfst-1.6.2/lib
Makefile:645: recipe for target 'fst_test' failed
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/kkoenen/stt/kaldi-master/tools/openfst-1.6.2/src/test'
Makefile:1054: recipe for target 'check-am' failed
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/kkoenen/stt/kaldi-master/tools/openfst-1.6.2/src/test'
Makefile:358: recipe for target 'check-recursive' failed
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/kkoenen/stt/kaldi-master/tools/openfst-1.6.2/src'
Makefile:414: recipe for target 'check-recursive' failed
```

// edit ; I moved to CentOS. Installation of Kaldi was a breeze. OpenFST was correctly installed in the process.